# Debugging Silverlight Bindings

Tags: silverlight, debugging, data-binding

I have a binding in Silverlight that is causing my application to exit. An unhandled exception is not throw; I just get a white screen.

I am not seeing anything from the binding engine in the output window.

Does anyone have any ideas for debugging this issue?

Comment: Silverlight 5 can't come fast enough- breakpoints on binding statements.  Woohoo!

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use Karl Shiflett's [Glimpse for Silverlight](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/glimpse-for-silverlight-viewing-exceptions-and-binding-errors/) for that.

Also, I just "heard" Laurent Bugnion on [twitter](http://twitter.com/LBugnion/status/4922574340) recommend using a mock Converter on a binding to figure out why it's failing. That's a good idea in case you're unsure as to what values are being fed to the binding.

Answer (score 0):

Dave, dont get too excited about the XAML debugging in SL5. I have been building projects for a few weeks now in SL5 and all I can say is that the XAML debugger will break after very little use and all you will get back is the ridiculous error message saying that the PDB's cant be found. I have reset my VS2010 setting numerous times and still the debugger remains crippled. I have spend days if not weeks trying to get to the bottom of the cause and as usual there are no support documents or help sites for this issue. Debugging Silverlight databindings is a black box scenario and a huge weakness in this technology. There is no way of knowing what the XAML parser is doing or not doing as the case may be. I have just had to scrap a project because of a total failure of the bindings in the View. The VM is preforming correctly by all bindings on the view fail. People will tell you that the output window in VS2010 will indicate the binding errors. My experience is that you can have total failure of bindings and NO errors will be shown in the output window. If you get into this scenario there is simply no solution that I am aware of and even the bug ridden XAML debugger wont be able to help you.